# Is there a way to alias tmux commands?

Tags: tmux

tmux has a command mode that can be accessed via `C-b :` and I'm wondering if there is a way to alias commands in my `.tmux.conf` file like `split-window` to something I use more often like `vsp` in vim.

I know I can bind keyboard shortcuts with `bind` but can I alias commands as well?

Answer (score 14):

tmux 2.4 adds the `command-alias` array option which does this, so for example you can do

```
:set -s command-alias[10] vsp='split-window -h'
```

And then you can use `:vsp` in the command-prompt just like you'd expect.

Comment: How to list all the aliases you defined so far?

Comment: @SFbay007 `:list-commands` would make the most sense, but user-defined aliases don't show up in that list (yet!)

Comment: Since it’s an option (as in `set-option`), it’s just`tmux show-options command-alias`.

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't appear to be possible as of tmux 2.0.

One thing you *can* do, however, is send commands to the enclosing tmux session from the shell. This means that you can, for example, create a *bash* alias that can split windows:

```
alias vsp="tmux split-window -h"
```

You can then run `vsp` from your bash prompt to split the tmux window vertically. Depending on your specific use case, this might help.

It's also worth noting that, if minimising typing is the goal, tmux commands can be shortened to their shortest unambiguous prefix: `sp` does the same thing as `split-window`.

Answer (score 2):

There's a mod allowing not only alias but also create new commands in tmux: http://ershov.github.io/tmux/

For example:

```
proc vsp {args} { split-window -h {*}$args }
```

No external shell involved, no new processes spawned.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bind`. Here is an example alias for turning `mouse-mode` on and off:

```
bind m \
    set -g mode-mouse on \;\
    set -g mouse-resize-pane on \;\
    set -g mouse-select-pane on \;\
    set -g mouse-select-window on \;\
    display 'Mouse mode ON'

bind M \
    set -g mode-mouse off \;\
    set -g mouse-resize-pane off \;\
    set -g mouse-select-pane off \;\
    set -g mouse-select-window off \;\
    display 'Mouse mode OFF'
```

Now you can easily use `Ctrl+B m` to turn it on, and `Ctrl+B M` to turn it off (assuming `Ctrl+B` is your prefix)

Answer (score -1):

Yep. Using `bind-key` in you tmux.conf. For example to split tmux windows use:

```
bind-key v split-window -v #C-b v to split vertically
bind-key h split-window -h #C-b h horizontal
```

If you don't want to use prefix (C-b) just add -n param:

```
bind-key -n C-right next # C - → to move to next window.
```

Comment: Not sure this answers the original question.  I believe the original question is asking if commands executed from `command-prompt` can be aliased, **not** `bind-key`.  The functional equivalent of `alias vsp="split-window -h"`.  So someone can do something like `C-b :vsp` to do a vertical split like in Vim.